# Excel VBA font color

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating one vba script for the leave management. the issue I am facing is Fore color for the lookup text value is not changing.
[image]

code part is below

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim lngBlack As Long
    lngBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    If Me.ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1.Value), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("J:K"), 2, 0)
        Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = lngBlack
    Else
```

but instead of Black I am getting gray color.

Please advise

I required the fore color black for the lookup generated fields

Comment: Are the gray textboxes disabled?

Comment: FYI, no need to call the `RGB()` function, there's a constant defined for black - `vbBlack`.